# Particle system without OpenGL and other libraries

Tags: c#, graphics2d, particles, particle-system

I have to make a program on particle systems in C# and I'm using Visual studio 2010. I must not use any libraries like OpenGl, ... I can use just Graphisc library from C#. I tried to read some tutorials and lectures but I still don't know how to implement it.

Can anybody help me understand how I should decompose my problem? Or direct me maybe on some useful tutorials? It´s new for me and I'm kinda stuck.

**My task:**

> Program a simple generator luminous particles in the shape of a geyser from a point generator, view the particles as different colored dots moving across a single track on a black background in parallel projection.

Answer (score 1):

Look up `BackgroundWorker` and `RenderTargetBitmap` it is probably best to do this in WPF

Psuedo code

```
backgroundWorker()
{
    while(isRunning)
    {
        update()
        draw()
    }
 }

 update()
 {
     for each all particles
     {
         update gravity and/or relativity to other particles
     }
 }

 draw()
 {
     clear bitmap

     for each all particles
     {
         draw your particle
     }

     set it to your container
 }
```

This is based upon a game loop

Comment: +1. Except there is no reason to use any kind of background worker for this task (or even for most games - update everything 30-60 times a second on main thread would be enough)

Answer (score 1):

Though not a complete answer, here is how I would break down the problem if it were my task:

1. Find a way to render a single particle (perhaps as a dot or a ball). I recommend starting with WPF.
2. Find a way to "move" that particle programmatically (i.e. by rendering it in different places over time).
3. Create a `Particle` class that can store its current state (position, velocity, acceleration) and can be moved (i.e. `SetPosition`, `SetVelocity`...)
4. Create a `World` class the represents a 3-dimensional space and keeps track of all the particles in it. The `World` will know the laws of physics and will be responsible for moving particles around given their current state.
5. Create a bunch of `Particle`s that have the same initial starting position but random initial acceleration vectors. Add those `Particle`s to the `World`. The `World` will automatically update their positions from then on.
6. Apply what you learned in steps 1 and 2 to have your `World` graphically represent all of its `Particle`s.

**Edit:** Step 7 would be to "run step 6 in a loop". The loop code provided by noHDD is a very good basic framework: continuously `update` the *state* of the world and then `draw` the results.

Comment: I have done something like that with WPF (just for the fun of it): http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2594/15 – Creating an ellipse for every particle is a bit wasteful, though ;)